# bash string replacement in parallel command

Tags: string, bash, parallel-processing, substitution

I am running `gdalinfo` command in parallel to obtain statistics from `*.tif` files

`find *tif  -printf "%f\n" | parallel -j 5 "/usr/local/bin/gdalinfo -mm  -stats -hist -json {} > {}.json"`

`{}` will be replaced by file being processed e,g. `SRTM.tif`, therefore output file named: `SRTM.tif.json`

How to do string subtitution on `{}`?

Using loops in Bash, I normally do `${f%.tif}.json` but it does not work (we do not have a bash variable) and also tried `awk` but no success.

Comment: How about `find ... | cut -d"." -f1 | parallel ... `

Comment: The final command would be:
`find *tif  -printf "%f\n"  | cut -d "." -f1  | parallel -j 5 "/usr/local/bin/gdalinfo -mm  -stats -hist -json {}.tif > {}.json"`

Comment: Looking at your `find`, please make sure that you want to do  `find *tif-printf "%f\n"` (which looks at all the paths `*tif`) instead of `find . -type f -name '*tif'` (which prints all files ending with `tif` under the current directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find tif files woth something like

```
find . -name "*.tif" -print | cut -d "." -f1 |
   parallel -j 5 "/usr/local/bin/gdalinfo -mm -stats -hist -json {}.tif > {}.json"
```

Edit: Or, with the suggestion in the other respose:

```
find . -name "*.tif" -print | 
   parallel -j 5 "/usr/local/bin/gdalinfo -mm -stats -hist -json {.}.tif > {.}.json"
```

Answer (score 3):

In `parallel`, `{.}` is the input-line without extension. So use that instead of `{}`. If you really want to do complicated string manipulation, use `{= perl expression=}`.